# How to instantiate a list with a specific numbers of values without know the value?

Tags: c#, wpf, livecharts

I'm using `LiveChart` of wpf, and I want instantiate a list of `Decimal` with 30 values (just as space as an array), actually I did:

```
public SeriesCollection MonthProfit {get;set;} = new SeriesCollection();

 int i = 0;
 MonthProfit[0].Values = new ChartValues<decimal>();
 MonthProfit[0].Values[i] = 25;
```

but I get:

> Index out of range

how can I define 30 values inside the index `0`?

Comment: I've added answer that assumes you've set up `MonthProfit` elsewhere, so that `MonthProfit[0]` actually exists, and that it's only the last line of your code that is throwing an exception. If it's `MonthProfit[0].Values = new ChartValues<decimal>();` that's throwing an exception, that suggests you haven't added a series to `MonthProfit` to start with. (This is where a [mcve] would make it easier to help you - that doesn't need to have a UI, but just be a complete example which shows which aspects of the initialization you've already done.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks to me like you could use the `ChartValues` constructor that accepts an `IEnumerable<T>`:

```
MonthProfit[0].Values = new ChartValues<decimal>(Enumerable.Repeat(0m, 30));
```